# Failsafe do not generate report, if there are no tests executed

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

If there are no testcases executed by failsafe, it still generates a report under `/failsafe-reports/failsafe-summary.xml` with content:

```
<failsafe-summary result="254"/>
```

Is there a way to avoid failsafe to generate this file, if there are no testcases (surefire also does not create the xml file if there are no test files to execute)?

Thanks in advance!